# How to Exclude some Folders when all Folders are removing in MSBuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

i have a MsBuild.targets file which can remove all folder except some folders, in this example we exclude en-us and fa-IR:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="RemoveFolders" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RemovingFiles Include="$(OutDir)*\*.mui" Exclude="$(OutDir)en-us\*.mui;$(OutDir)fa-IR\*.mui" />
      <RemovingFolders Include="@(RemovingFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(RemovingFolders)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

now i want to make this codes dynamic with a Property, for example called **ExcludedLanguages**, so i can exclude every folder i want:

```
<ExcludedLanguages>en-us;cn-zh</ExcludedLanguages>
```

but i dont know how to do this?
i tried this codes but not working and all folders are removing.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Comma-separated list of languages to exclude -->
    <ExcludedLanguages>en-US,fa-IR</ExcludedLanguages>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="RemoveFolders" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RemovingFiles Include="$(OutDir)*\*.mui" Exclude="@(ExcludedLanguages->'%(Identity)')\*.mui" />
      <RemovingFolders Include="@(RemovingFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(RemovingFolders)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: `@(ExcludedLanguages->'%(Identity)')` expands to `en-us;cn-zh`. Your `Exclude` value `en-us;cn-zh\*.mui` which will never match anything in the `Include` value of `$(OutDir)*\*.mui`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back to your working example, the `Exclude` is `$(OutDir)en-us\*.mui;$(OutDir)fa-IR\*.mui`.

Given `en-us;cn-zh` you want a value for the `Exclude` of `$(OutDir)en-us\*.mui;$(OutDir)cn-zh\*.mui`. Put another way, for each excluded language value **LANG** you want to create a string of the form `$(OutDir)LANG\*.mui`.

Building from your working example may look like the following:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Comma-separated list of languages to exclude -->
    <ExcludedLanguages>en-US,fa-IR</ExcludedLanguages>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Create an Item collection from the ExcludedLanguages property -->
    <ExcludedLanguage Include="$(ExcludedLanguages.Replace(',', ';'))" />
  <ItemGroup>
  
  <Target Name="RemoveFolders" AfterTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Use transform on ExcludedLanguage to produce a property -->
      <ExcludeByLanguage>@(ExcludedLanguage->'$(OutDir)%(Identity)\*.mui')<ExcludeByLanguage>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Use the generated property to exclude -->
      <RemovingFiles Include="$(OutDir)*\*.mui" Exclude="$(ExcludeByLanguage)" />
      <RemovingFolders Include="@(RemovingFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(RemovingFolders)" />
  </Target>
```

(I haven't tested this code. If you find an issue leave a comment and I will address it.)